# Banker's Rounding in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, bankers-rounding

Is there any internal function in Oracle to support Banker's rounding, I need to use half to odd Banker's rounding in a select query

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To round to the nearest odd integer:

```
CASE
  WHEN MOD( ABS( value ), 2 ) = 1.5
  THEN TRUNC( value )
  ELSE ROUND( value )
END
```

To round to the nearest odd hundredth:

```
CASE
  WHEN MOD( ABS( value ), 0.02 ) = 0.015
  THEN TRUNC( value, 2 )
  ELSE ROUND( value, 2 )
END
```

Comment: how could a MOD with 2 be other than 1 or 0 ?

Comment: Because you are not just passing positive integers into the function: `MOD( 3.5, 2 )` is `1.5` and `MOD( -4.5, 2 )` is `-0.5`.

Comment: thanks, this one worked for first decimal digit half to odd, but was looking for an internal Oracle function for this purpose as first priority...

Comment: @VivekGupta See my previous edit for rounding to nearest odd hundredth - there is no single Oracle function that will do this but `MOD()`, `ABS()`, `TRUNC()` and `ROUND()` are all simple Oracle functions.